# How to convert synchronous blocking shared memory model code to asynchronous coroutines running on thread pool?

Tags: pthreads, threadpool, green-threads

While there are lots of solutions matching my question partially, I'd like to know if a complete match exists. It's hard to find a complete solution because of these partial ones occupying search results. This should be a runtime framework and (optionally) a transformation required to source language code when the language doesn't support coroutines.

There are libraries like lthread having lthread_cond_wait() API, but every lthread is bounded by a single pthread. I'd like lightweight threads to be able to run in several pthreads. They should be arbitrary picked by thread pool. Either single-threaded schedulers or global lock schedulers don't match. I think we can do better.

lthreads is also not an option because it neither involves source code transformation nor avoids it like protothreads.

Several green-threading runtimes (Erlang, Limbo) don't match because they are limited to CSP (communicating sequential processes) model only, but I'd like to have shared memory model synchronization primitives as well: mutexes, condition variables, rwlocks.

Transformation involves:

1. Transforming stack contexts into objects in heap
2. Transforming mutex calls into manipulating disabling and activating jobs on thread pool and publish-subscribe
3. Condition variables should also be transformed into publish-subscribe realtionships
4. It would be nice to have Ada-style rendezvous

I failed to do straightforward runtime implementation due to potential deadlocks in publish-subscribe mechanism without using global lock or single scheduler thread, but I still think this is possible.

Comment: Over past time I've found MapuSoft AdaMagic (Ada->C/C++) compiler. Given that we provide mutexes and condition variables for RTS, we can have nice rendezvous. Another finding is Continuation Passing C. It transforms stack contexts into objects, exactly like desired. They don't work together because Ada exceptions are mapped to either C++ exceptions or C longjmp(), and CPC doesn't support any. Probably can be solved, but not yet. Also, CPC scheduler is single threaded. Also, universal hybrid mutex+cond solution is yet to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: lthread author.

You can launch several pthreads and run an lthread scheduler in each one (this is done automagically by calling lthread_run() in the pthread function). This way each pthread will run a bunch of lthreads.